# Flex and Django for web application - Does it work well together?

Tags: django, apache-flex

I'm building from scratch a web application that is not trivial (have some algorithms and calculations in the backend) but not too complex (it doesn't have to process lots of records during runtime.)
We thought about using Django for the backend in order to be able to develop the application fast with flex based GUI.

I'm a Java developer with no experience with Django so basically I wanted to know if using Flex and Django together is a good option in terms of ease of development and maintenance? I saw that there are several libraries such as pyAMF and DjangoAMF for this purpose, but since Django is also about html templates and MVC, does flex really work well with django?

Thanks

Comment: While django is also about html templates and MVC, its data modeling makes things seem so easy. Python, the language django is based on, should be fast enough for your algorithms and calculations. It wouldn't hurt to use django.

Comment: Thanks. Python is a great language and i also tried using django and it was very easy and fast, but will the integration with flex make sense or will it give me a hard time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't have to return HTML, that is just a common use case. Even in 'regular' web applications, a Django view might return json, xml, or yaml for an ajax response. You can use templates or not, whatever is easier for the task at hand.

You might find this article helpful - just substitute 'Django' wherever you see 'PHP'

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_php_architecture_02.html